# How do you test a function that interacts with a functional component's UI in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been looking all around for an answer to this and I am not seeing it. I have a file that has a functional component and a function. The function is supposed to interact with the JSX of the functional component. The code is like this. In a FunctionalComponent.test.js file, how am I supposed to test that the color() function changes the property of the FunctionalComponent properly?

```
function color() {
  //Change the color of the element with id 'container'
}

export default function FunctionalComponent() {
  return(
    <div id="container">
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you are using jest, you can check if get the element by id and check if it has the updated style rule applied by the `color()` function. Something like `expect(container).toHaveStyleRule('color', 'red')`.

Comment: how do you call that `color` function? or when - on some event?